# reading json data from external url

Tags: php, json, wordpress

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://uapi.alidays.it/service/2.0.0/rs/alidays/applications/fluidtravel/public/baskets/5660609ee4b0ab55863d6c42/contents/selected');
$json =json_decode($str,true);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($json,true) . '</pre>';
 foreach($json['data'] as $item['value']['baskettile']) {
   echo $item['value']['baskettile']['type'];

    echo '<br>';
 }
```

i tried to access the data like this  but it says Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: `PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'type' in - on line 6`

Comment: yes i know that i when i tried i got it do you know why i got that @Quentin

Comment: You got that? Why didn't you mention that in your question then?

Comment: i tried so many times so i think that is not the problem i guess that is the reason i have not included @Quentin

Comment: If I was to guess, you probably want to iterate over `$json['data']` and access the items as `$item['value']['baskettile']['type']`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `baskettile` is an object with properties like `type` and `status`.

It is not an array. It doesn't make sense to iterate over it with `foreach(... in ...)`.

Just access the values directly.

```
$json['data']['0']['value']['baskettile']['type']
```

Comment: you are life saver @Quentin

Comment: but i want to iterate loop @Quentin

Comment: @SaidaRao — What do you want to loop over? The thing you were trying to loop over wasn't an array.

Comment: why i am looking for iteration is if my id have more items then i can not write code each one right so that is the reason  i am looking for that and updated like you said but its not working for iteration

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your code. Chances are `$item` is not what you think it is.
The quickest way is to do a `var_dump($item)` in your foreach. From there you will see that the variable either is not an array or the key does not exist.

Comment: foreach ($json['data'] as  $item) {                                                                                                               echo "experiences id =====".$item['value']['baskettile']['type']."</br>";   }                                                                                                           this one worked for me i hope this will help for others